# Get MYSql Data in to a Drop Down List in an HTML Form in an HTML Table

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, html-table

This is a two part Question - sorry!

I see there are lots of answers to the first part, I.E. How to populate a Drop Down List in a Form.

**PART 1**
However, when I place the Form (with the DDL) in a Table it all goes wrong and doesn't work.

**Question 1**
Why isn't the DDL populating? - There are 4 names in the table each with various other columns - ID, Name, Nickname etc.

**Part 2**
I want to return the 'ID' of the selected 'Name', which I then will add to another table with other data in it. At the moment the 'ID" is not being passed to the PHP that is writing to the file.

**Question 2**
What do I need to add to my code to return the ID of the selected Name?  I.E. I don't want the Name in the table, just the ID of the Name.

Code is here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );

// Check connection
if ( $conn->connect_error ) {
  die( "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error );
}
?>

<body>    
<form method="post" action="property.php">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Property Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Agent Name:</td>
      <td>
          <select>

            <?php
            $res = mysqli_query( $conn, "select * from Names" );
            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $res ) ) {
              ?>

            <option value="id">

            <?php echo $row["name"] ?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be awesome!!

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<?php echo $row{"name"} ?>` with `<?php echo $row["name"] ?>` :)

Comment: Thanks!  Thanks - that filled the DDL! But the ID attached to the DDL Item, is still not being returned...